# t-sql how to select records without a duplicated one column

Tags: t-sql, duplicates

I want to select rows for all employess without repeating the data in one column.

For example I have two rows where salary (before raise) is displayed, how can I display only the largest figure without duplication.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update your question with the table structures, some sample data and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Row_Number function
Here is a sample code

```
    select * from (
select *, 
row_number() over (partition by empid, name, department order by salary desc) as rn
from employee
) employee where rn = 1
```

You can find Row_Number() with Partition By clause sample at http://www.kodyaz.com

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, then a simple `MAX` function and `GROUP BY` would work.

```
SELECT   EmployeeId, OtherColumns, MAX(Salary)
FROM     tblEmployees
GROUP BY EmployeeId, OtherColumns
```